# core-js error when trying download firebase package

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-install, core-js

I get this error when trying to download firebase but another package I don't see. What can I do?

Also when I tried  `npm install core-js@3.24.3`  I achieved the same error

I removed folders inside npm-caches from %appdata% and tried `npm install` again. Sadly i see the same error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the correct solution but i have a another laptop have never codded in. So that It works